# WebBrowserControl uninitialized when coming back from sub screen

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have a page with a WebBrowserControl + some buttons at the bottom. When i click on of the buttons, a subpage is opened (NavigationService.Navigate(...)).
Now, when i'm on the sub page and close that page via `NavigationService.GoBack()` the WebBrowserControl is just white. Seems like it is completely uninitialized. Also checking `WebBrowserControl.Source`gives `null`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this you would want to make sure you are keeping track of objects in isolated storage or known as TombStoning on the WP7.

you would want to save page state onNavigatingFrom() and Load it onNavigationTo().

That should work. :)